# ANTLR is taking the wrong branch

Tags: antlr, grammar

I have this very simple grammar:

```
grammar LispExp;

expression : LITERAL #LiteralExp
            | '(' '-' expression ')' #UnaryMinusExp
            | '(' OP expression expression ')' #OpExp
            | '(' 'if' expression expression expression ')' #IfExp;

OP : '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '==' | '<';
LITERAL : '0'|('1'..'9')('0'..'9')*;
WS       : ('\t' | '\n' | '\r' | ' ') -> skip;
```

It should be able to parse a "lisp-like" expression, but when I try to parse this:

```
(+ (+ 5 (* 7 (/ 5 (- 2 (- 9) ) ) ) ) 8)
```

ANTLR fails to recognize the last unary minus, and generates the following (with antlr v4) :

```
(expression ( + (expression ( + (expression 5) (expression ( * (expression 7) (expression ( / (expression 5) (expression ( - (expression 2))) ( -) 9 )) expression ))
```

[image: AST]

So, how can I make ANTLR understand the priority of unary minus over binary expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a combined `grammar LispExp`, as opposed to separate `lexer grammar LispExpLexer` and `parser grammar LispExpParser`. When working with combined grammars, if you use a string literal in a parser rule the code generator will create anonymous tokens according to those string literals, and silently override the lexer.

In this case, your `expression` rule includes the string literal `'-'`. All instances of `-` in your input will be assigned this token type, which means they will *not ever* have the token type `OP`. Your input contains a subexpression `(- 2 (- 9) )` which can only be parsed if the first `-` is an `OP` token, so according to the parser you have a syntax error in your input.

If you update your code to use separate lexer and parser grammars, any attempt to use a string literal in the parser grammar which is not defined in the lexer grammar will produce an error when you attempt to generate your lexer and parser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't had much time to try it but I will definitly do it ASAP. Still, do you know if it's possible to achieve the same result with  a mixed grammar ? And are mixed grammar considere bad practice ?